# Laravel | Bootstrap 5 pills - class active/show

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

how can I correct add show and active class to bootstrap 5 pills?? Now I try to do something like this:

```
<div class="nav-head">
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
@foreach($blocks as $item)
@foreach ($item->offers->take(4) as $offer)
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
           <a class="nav-link {{ $offer->first ? 'active' : ''}} {{ $offer->first ? 'show' : ''}}" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-{{ $offer->id }}">{{ $offer->title }}</a>
     </li>
@endforeach
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
@foreach($blocks as $item)
@foreach ($item->offers as $offer)
       <div class="tab-pane fade {{ $offer->first ? 'active' : ''}} {{ $offer->first ? 'show' : ''}}" id="tabs-{{ $offer->id }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="live-chat-tab">
...
      </div>
@endforeach
@endforeach
</div>
```

Line:

```
{{ $offer->first ? 'active' : ''}} {{ $offer->first ? 'show' : ''}}
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `$loop->first` not  `$offer->first`

When `looping`, a `$loop` variable will be available inside of your loop. This variable provides access to some useful bits of information such as the current loop index and whether this is the first or last iteration through the loop:

```
{{$loop->first ? 'active' : ''}} {{$loop->first ? 'show' : ''}}
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: I suppose active and show could just be done together, instead of 2 ternary statements! `{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}`

Comment: @Siddharth Bhansali  definitely i will agree  with your suggestion. I was just pointing to $loop.

Comment: Ah yeah, and I forgot to add the show class to my code, lol.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali thats fine i got it whats your point you wanted to tell. :)